# UUID: required String, found:int

Tags: java, hash, uuid, incompatibletypeerror

I'm shortening my UUID into a four digit number using the following code:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Generate short UUID (13 characters)
 *
 * @return short UUID
 */

public class UUIDshortener
{
    public static String shortUUID()
{
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    //long l = ByteBuffer.wrap(uuid.toString().getBytes()).getLong();
    //return Long.toString(l, Character.MAX_RADIX);
    return uuid.toString().hashCode();
}
}
```

I am getting the following error:
[image: compiler error message]

If anyone knows how to fix this it would be much appreciated. Is it as simple as changing it to an int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method signature says you will return a `String`

```
public static String shortUUID()
```

but you are actually returning an `int`, since that's the return type of the `hashCode()` method

```
return uuid.toString().hashCode();
```

Just change your method sig to:

```
public static int shortUUID()
```

---

EDIT - to answer comment

There is no `getInt()` method on the `UUID` class, so `uuid.getInt().hashCode()` won't compile.  If you want to simplify your return statement, you can just `hashCode()` directly on uuid like this:

```
    return uuid.hashCode();
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I change "return uuid.toString().hashCode();" to "return uuid.toInt().hashCode();" also?